# Haveing trouble getting rid of the extra space to the right of my content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap 3 grid on my website and I am having trouble with getting rid of this extra space thats to the right of all my content. Allowing the bottom scrollbar to be visible and move. I dont want to hide the scrollbar I know How to do that. I simply just want to fit the content to the page so that there isnt reason for the bottom scrollbar to display. Just want to make my content fit to the page. So I can continue redesigning.....

www.Trillumonopoly.com/index2.html

Comment: How do you expect answer without providing your code here, and also the website right click is disabled to use `insepct element` tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this should do it

```
.container-fluid {
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
}
```

AND delete .row from where your .navbar-default also are. :)